# java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect (I did read the others before posting)

Tags: java, sockets, bind

I know there are a ton of these posts, but this is a little different. We are using vended code for part of our data processing system, and part of the system sends emails to clients if certain events take place on data insertion or deletion. Recently we have started getting address already in use exceptions. We checked the repository history, and nothing has changed in our code in the last 6 months for this system. We have already tried the typical solutions for this issue including increasing the number of connections allowed to the port with little success. We had a meeting with the vendor, and I asked if anything had changed in their code, and if they would assure that all connections in their code are explicitly closed. They indicated that they are explicitly closing all sockets. However they didn't show us the code so there is no way for us to know if this is true other than taking their word for it. So, the only thing I can think of to do is continue to increase the number of connections to the port until we stop getting bind exceptions. So, what is the industry standard for max number of connections to port 25; is there one? Also if anyone has any other suggestions I would greatly appreciate it? Thanks so much in advance, Robert

```
20210505112127.716 ERROR m.fiserv.ppx.business.notification.EmailNotifier : MessagingException from notify
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: SERVER.URL.COM, port: 25;
 nested exception is:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1545)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:453)
Caused by:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:90)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:380)
20210505131529.950 ERROR erv.ppx.web.controller.AuditReportViewController : Error while generating HTML
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error writing to OutputStream writer : CorpAdminAuditReport
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHtmlExporter.exportReport(JRHtmlExporter.java:496)
at com.fiserv.ppx.web.controller.AuditReportViewController.generateReport(AuditReportViewController.java:184)
Caused by:
com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.ClosedConnectionException: OutputStream encountered error during write
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferOutputStream.write(WCCByteBufferOutputStream.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTOutputStream.write(SRTOutputStream.java:97)
20210505140706.240 ERROR com.fiserv.ppx.business.db.DBConnectionUtil      : Exception in getting for AppServer connection from DataSource.
com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: J2CA1010E: Connection not available; timed out waiting for 180,005 seconds.
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.toSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:1680)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:661)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:611)
Caused by:
com.ibm.websphere.ce.j2c.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: J2CA1010E: Connection not available; timed out waiting for 180,005 seconds.
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1781)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3834)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3082)
20210505140731.341 ERROR com.fiserv.ppx.business.db.DBConnectionUtil      : Exception in getting for AppServer connection from DataSource.
com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: J2CA1010E: Connection not available; timed out waiting for 180,010 seconds.
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.toSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:1680)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:661)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:611)
Caused by:
com.ibm.websphere.ce.j2c.ConnectionWaitTimeoutException: J2CA1010E: Connection not available; timed out waiting for 180,010 seconds.
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1781)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3904)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3082)
20210505140731.341 ERROR com.fiserv.ppx.sso.controller.SSOController      : SSO Configuration error
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fiserv.ppx.business.db.PPXDbTransactionManager.<init>(PPXDbTransactionManager.java:60)
at com.fiserv.ppx.sso.impl.SSOLoginAuthenticator.authenticateSSOUser(SSOLoginAuthenticator.java:157)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve]?

Comment: I wish I could but the code that handles this section of our system is vended code that I don't have access to that is the reason I'm having problems resolving the issue. If it was our code I would just run it through the debugger, get the stack dump, etc. The vendor is not being very helpful so I'm trying to do my best to resolve the issue.